# Disable a specific services in Windows 7

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am using a `Windows 7` and I want to **Disable** some *Services*, 
How can I do this?

- For my machine only?
- For some machines inside the Active Directory I can control?
- For all machines inside the Active Directory I can control?

Some of the *services* I would like to **disable** are:

- [Microsoft Lync](https://products.office.com/en-gb/skype-for-business/online-meetings)
- [snare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snare_(software))

Comment: Block it from what? You want to prevent it from running? Prevent it from accessing the network?

Comment: Block it? You mean disabling it right??

Answer (score 1):

If it's a computer (or group of computers) managed by Active Directory you can do this with Group Policy.

The settings is under Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > System Services.

[image: Block Service]

If it's just on one computer you can just disable the service (Start > Run > Services.mmc) and change the Startup Type to Disabled.

Comment: It doesn't just have to be on the network . I use GPO to enforce settings on my local machine for children.